# How can I change bootstrap 3 dropdown background color after click?

Tags: html

[image: before]
[image: after]

The problem is when i click the dropdown the text go black so i need to change it to white. when i remove the #tab color i will change to #9e9e9d.

#tab{
color: black
}

```
#tab:hover {
  color: white;
}

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="index.html" id="tab">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="Beverages.html" id="tab">MENU</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="tab">PROMOTION <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Christmas Bundle</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="About.html" id="tab">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="Faq.html" id="tab">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave a solution on `jquery`, since you mentioned `bootstrap`. The solution uses method `toggleClass()`.

Was it necessary?

```js
$('.dropdown').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('a_color_active');
  $('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('ul_color_active');
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  background-color: pink;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown a,
.dropdown-menu a {
  color: unset;
}

.dropdown.a_color_active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-menu.ul_color_active {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="tab">PROMOTION <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Christmas Bundle</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

second:

```js
$('.dropdown').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('a_color_active');
  $('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('ul_color_active');
});
```

```css
.nav.navbar-nav a {
  color: black;
}

.nav.navbar-nav a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.nav.navbar-nav a,
.dropdown-menu a {
  color: unset;
}

.dropdown.a_color_active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-menu.ul_color_active {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html" id="tab">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="Beverages.html" id="tab">MENU</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="tab">PROMOTION <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Christmas Bundle</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="About.html" id="tab">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="Faq.html" id="tab">FAQ</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it did not solve the black color in the background of active dropdown its still black and only the color of <li> has change. try to view my sample screenshot to know what i'm saying for thanks.

Comment: try to make both red background color not active and active to the dropdown

Comment: sorry, man. I really want to help you, but I can't understand what result you want.

Comment: wait i will add some screenshot

Comment: kindly check again my post bro

Comment: see second solution (second snippet)

Comment: glad to help, bro :)

Comment: I will add to the comment .. Please note that all `a` tags use one identifier `tab` - this is incorrect. The identifier must be unique for each tag. I changed the css. There was a `#tab`, and now it is `.nav.navbar-nav a`.